# Need faster code to relay/publish a SQL query to a spreadsheet

Tags: sql-server, google-apps-script

I have a JDBC connection in google sheets to query my sql server. I'm a newbie to JDBC so I've cobbled together other peoples code and it does work, but it seems like when the query has a lot of output that it takes a long time to write to the sheet.

Could you tell me if there's a better/more efficient code for putting it into the rows and columns than the code I'm using. I'm only concerned about the output section of the code.

```
function createtestDispositionHistoryTable() {
  var conn = Jdbc.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://123.45.67.89;databaseName=dbname","me","myPassword");
  var stmt = conn.createStatement();
  var rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT agent.firstname, agentdispositionhistory.dispositionid, agentdispositionhistory.dispositiontime, leadlist.name, program.name, agentdispositionhistory.sale\
                              FROM agentdispositionhistory\
                              INNER JOIN lead\
                              ON agentdispositionhistory.leadid=lead.id\
                              INNER JOIN leadlist\
                              ON lead.leadlistid=leadlist.id\
                              INNER JOIN program\
                              ON leadlist.programid=program.id\
                              INNER JOIN agent\
                              ON agentdispositionhistory.agentid=agent.id\
                              WHERE agentdispositionhistory.dispositionid IN\
(1971,\
1976,\
1977,\
1978,\
1979,\
1980,\
1982,\
1983,\
1984,\
1995,\
2000,\
2001,\
2002,\
2003,\
2004,\
2006,\
2007,\
2008,\
2019,\
2023,\
2025,\
2026,\
2027,\
2029,\
2030,\
2031,\
2032)");

  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  doc.insertSheet('Agent Disposition Table test');
  var sheet = doc.getSheets()[0];
  doc.appendRow(["Name", "Disposition", "Date", "Lead List", "Program", "Sale"]);

  var cell = doc.getRange('a1');
  var row = 1;
  while(rs.next()) {
    cell.offset(row, 0).setValue(rs.getString(1));
    cell.offset(row, 1).setValue(rs.getString(2));
    cell.offset(row, 2).setValue(rs.getString(3));
    cell.offset(row, 3).setValue(rs.getString(4));
    cell.offset(row, 4).setValue(rs.getString(5));
    cell.offset(row, 5).setValue(rs.getString(6));
    row++;
  }
  rs.close();
  stmt.close();
  conn.close();
}
```

The specific section I'm referring to is:

```
var cell = doc.getRange('a1');
      var row = 1;
      while(rs.next()) {
        cell.offset(row, 0).setValue(rs.getString(1));
        cell.offset(row, 1).setValue(rs.getString(2));
        cell.offset(row, 2).setValue(rs.getString(3));
        cell.offset(row, 3).setValue(rs.getString(4));
        cell.offset(row, 4).setValue(rs.getString(5));
        cell.offset(row, 5).setValue(rs.getString(6));       
        row++;
```

Thanks for any help its much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's so slow because you write every single value with a separate call to the sheet.

It is much faster to prepare a 2d array and write everything at once.
Something like this (not tested)

```
var output = [];
var rowData;

while(rs.next()) {
  rowData = [1,2,3,4,5,6].map(function(i) {
    return rs.getString(i);
  });
  output.push(rowData);
}

if (output.length) {
  doc.getRange(1, 1, output.length, output[0].length).setValues(output);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I will research the 2d array and work on getting this to work. Just knowing what to google helps a lot.

Comment: Try replacing everythin from the cell to the end of the while with my code. It should hopefully work

Comment: I think its very close to working. It runs without error but there is no output. The execution transcript shows that its getting data also.

Comment: Here is key part of execution transcript:

[16-10-19 10:42:47:643 CDT] Sheet.getRange([1, 1, 4341, 6]) [0.001 seconds]
[16-10-19 10:42:49:685 CDT] Range.setValues([[[Emily Bromley, 1976, 2016-09-29 13:45:16.243, General List 2, Pro Pest STL Commercial, 0.00], [Emily Bromley, 1976, 2016-09-29 13:45:05.54, General List 2, Pro Pest STL Commercial, 0.00], [Emily Bromley, 1976, 2016-09-29 13:43:10.96, , , ], [, , , , , ], [, , , , , ], [, , , , , ], [, , , , , ], [, , , , , ], [, , , , , ], [, , , , , ], [, , , , , ], [, , , , , ], [, , , , , ], [, , , , , ], [, , , , , ], [, , , , , ], [, , , ,

Comment: Can you debug the script before the output.length check and look at the structure of output? The getRange call seems to work but the call makes it look like it's a one element array containing a 2d array.

Comment: Any ideas on how to debug that? Sorry its getting a little over my head.

Comment: next to the run script button there's a bug icon, you can put breakpoints next to the line numbers of the code

Comment: It works! After debugging the output looked good, I started to look at the other code, it seems that the doc.getSheets()[0] was throwing the whole thing off, I've cleaned that section up and it works like a charm now, and so much faster.  Thank you so much man, hope you have a good day!

Comment: Great, please consider accepting the answer if it helped you. Thanks :)